# Can Jenkins run several jobs in the same time

Tags: jenkins, build, automated-tests

I have Jenkins installed for running test automation running on Java, Maven,JMeter etc. The Builds are not generating deployment files and folders, but only reports for the tests.
Can I build several jobs one after another (almost in the same time) to run in parallel? they don't have to be exactly in the same time. I just want to make sure that starting the 2nd build won't stop/damage the 1st (already running) build.
Thanks

Comment: the answer is yes, you have to look in the job settings and set from there this feature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

Go to your job -> configuration and check: **Execute concurrent builds if necessary**

Doc:

> If this option is checked, Jenkins will schedule and execute multiple
>   builds concurrently (provided that you have sufficient executors and
>   incoming build requests.) This is useful on builds and test jobs that
>   take a long time, as each build will only contain a smaller number of
>   changes, and the total turn-around time decreases due to the shorter
>   time a build request spends waiting for the previous build to
>   complete. It is also very useful with parameterized builds, whose
>   individual executions are independent from each other.
>
> For other kinds of jobs, allowing concurrent executions of multiple
>   builds may be problematic, for example if it assumes a monopoly on a
>   certain resource, like database, or for jobs where you use Jenkins as
>   a cron replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your job -> configuration and check the Boolean: **`Do not allow concurrent builds`**