# I have two jobs in jenkins, I want to execute both the jobs simultaneously

Tags: jenkins

job 1 should execute first after 30-second job 2 should be executed.
how to achieve in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Quiet Period and Post build action to achieve this.

see these below links once.

[how to execute Jenkins job after specific time once the previous job completed successfully?(SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51017075/how-to-execute-jenkins-job-after-specific-time-once-the-previous-job-completed-s)

[Jenkins: build one job after another with some delay (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748993/jenkins-build-one-job-after-another-with-some-delay)

Comment: hi PALLAMOLLA SAI...   both jobs should start parallelly but with a minor delay, because the first job performs starting the server so need to start job 1 first and then job 2, job1 never ends.

Comment: Hey Harsha, are you trying to run a server locally on Jenkins machine?

Comment: could you please try this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280792/can-jenkins-run-several-jobs-in-the-same-time

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple ways and the procedure would change as per your requirement.

If you have a hard limit of 30 sec you can try below.

Have a parent job say 'A' (Which would start two jobs 'B' and 'C' simultaneously with a gap of 30seconds)

1. parent job (A) job will have a build step "trigger another job" where u can define job 'B' as a non blocking job
2. An execute shell for `sleep 30s`
3. parent job (A) job will have another build step "trigger another job" where u can define job 'C' as a non blocking job

If this answer has helped please vote up/Accept , so that others with same question can find this helpful

Comment: i am new to jenkins please provide the code to execute it..thank you.

Comment: sleep 30s is the only code u need , rest jenkins should provide you

Comment: You need to create a additional job which would act like a master job which is only used to start your jobs one after the other with a gap of 30 sec

Comment: In jenkins job you would have build step drop down , in there you could select 'Execute shell', inside execute shell you can add sleep 30s